# How to filter Today's Date Order in ngFor Angular 5?

Tags: angular, date, filter, ngfor

I want to filter by only Today's Date order on My Dashboard.Any Possible Solution for that?

```
{
      "added_on": "2018-07-19T12:50:02.369Z",
      "deleted": false,
      "_id": "5b001d7a57579f58422437e6",
      "restaurant_id": "5ab9d70f7c4f1e25a7304779",
      "user_id": null,
      "discount_total": 2,
      "__v": 0
}
```

Here is my data. The Date is on the field named added_on. So I want to filter my data of today's order on the dashboard.

Comment: are you want to filter data with current date OR Order data by current date

Comment: Order data by current date

Answer (score 2):

You can try with this solution.

I have create a demo on [**Stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/how-to-filter-todays-date-order-in-ngfor-angular-5?file=src%2Fapp%2Forder-by.pipe.ts)

> order-by.pipe.ts

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
@Pipe({
  name: 'orderBy',
})
export class OrderByPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(array: Array<any>, args: string): Array<any> {
    if (typeof args[0] === "undefined") {
      return array;
    }
    let direction = args[0][0];
    let column = args.replace('-', '');
    array.sort((a: any, b: any) => {
      let left = Number(new Date(a[column]));
      let right = Number(new Date(b[column]));
      return (direction === "-") ? right - left : left - right;
    });
    return array;
  }

}
```

> app.component.ts

```
data = [{
    "added_on": "2018-07-12T12:50:02.369Z",
    "deleted": false,
    "_id": "5b001d7a57579f58422437e6",
    "restaurant_id": "5ab9d70f7c4f1e25a7304779",
    "user_id": null,
    "discount_total": 1,
    "__v": 0
  }, {
    "added_on": "2018-07-19T12:50:02.369Z",
    "deleted": false,
    "_id": "5b001d7a57579f58422437e6",
    "restaurant_id": "5ab9d70f7c4f1e25a7304779",
    "user_id": null,
    "discount_total": 2,
    "__v": 0
  }, {
    "added_on": "2018-07-19T12:50:02.369Z",
    "deleted": false,
    "_id": "5b001d7a57579f58422437e6",
    "restaurant_id": "5ab9d70f7c4f1e25a7304779",
    "user_id": null,
    "discount_total": 3,
    "__v": 0
  }]
```

> app.component.html

```
*ngFor="let datas of data | orderBy:'-added_on'"
```